# json.loads() issue for MongoDB

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have following json file:

```
{'a': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}
```

I converted it into string and replaces ' --> "":

```
>>> x
'{"a": {"$gt": datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}'
```

Getting error in loading the json:

```
>>> json.loads(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has got resolved. The issue arising from the fact : “datetime.datetime not JSON serialize”

```
from json import dumps
from datetime import date, datetime

def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return obj.isoformat()
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))
```

After importing this function:

```
>>> x
{'a': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}
>>> x=dumps(x,default=json_serial)
>>> x
'{"a": {"$gt": "2020-01-01T00:00:00"}}'
>>>
>>>
>>> json.loads(x)
{'a': {'$gt': '2020-01-01T00:00:00'}}
>>>
```